# How to give button a default input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've put together a Codepen by mashing together a couple different examples by other people in order to get something pretty close to what I'm actually looking for. The only problem I have now is that I'd like to give the button in my example a default value of 3, rather than have somebody input a value of their choice, so that when the button is clicked, three images are selected at random.

I've tried

```
$(shuffle($all).slice(0, $("input").val(3))).addClass("selected");
```

whilst commenting out the input type, but that didn't work.

Thanks in advance for any tips!

http://codepen.io/asyi/pen/XMVwVg

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">    <title>This Webpage</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">

    <div class="square">

    </div>

    <div class="square">


    </div>

    <div class="square">

    </div>

    <div class="square">

    </div>

    </div>

    <button>Click to win!:</button>
    <input type="text" size="3" value="3" />


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
    </body>
```

CSS

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}



#container {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#container > div {
    width: 50%;
    height: 20vw;
    border: white 10px solid;
}

.selected {
    background: tan;
    border: red 2px solid;
}

.square {
    background-image: url('https://placebear.com/300/200');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 85%;
    background-position: center;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function shuffle(array) {
      var m = array.length, t, i;

      // While there remain elements to shuffle…
      while (m) {

        // Pick a remaining element…
        i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

        // And swap it with the current element.
        t = array[m];
        array[m] = array[i];
        array[i] = t;
      }

      return array;
    }

    $(function() {
        $("button").click(function() {
            var $all =         $(".square").removeClass("selected");
            $(shuffle($all).slice(0, $("input").val())).addClass("selected");
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: `$(shuffle($all).slice(0, 3)).addClass("selected");` should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, it worked! Thank you @DavidDomain